# How to include '+' in Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I wrote a regular expression (in Objective C) to find the following substrings in a string:

```
+RA, -RA, RA, +SN, -SN, SN, +DZ, -DZ, DZ
```

The original RE is:

```
NSString* expression = @"^.*?(RA|SN|DZ).*?$";
```

However, since .* implies practically anything, the RE also detects substring "DSNT", for instance, which I am trying to avoid. So instead of ^.*?, I am trying to write something like

```
@"^(-|+)?(RA|SN|DZ).*?$";
```

But since the "+" sign has a special meaning in RE, it does not work as intended: the substrings are not identified. So, I wonder how to incorporate the "+" sign in the RE code above.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[+-](?:RA|SN|DZ)\b" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:subject options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [subject length])];
NSUInteger matchCount = [matches count];
if (matchCount) {
    for (NSUInteger matchIdx = 0; matchIdx < matchCount; matchIdx++) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:matchIdx];
        NSRange matchRange = [match range];
        NSString *result = [subject substringWithRange:matchRange];
    }
}
else {  // Nah... No matches.
     }
```

**Explanation**

- The character class `[+-]` matches a plus or a minus
- The non-capture group `(?:RA|SN|DZ)` matches one of the three tokens
- The code iterates through the matches

Comment: Thanks. So, the way it is written now, DSNT will also be picked up. But the following seems to work as it should:`NSString* expression = @"(^|\\s)[+-]?(?:DZ|RA|SN).*?$";`

Comment: May I ask another question: Why in the following regex `@"(^|\\s)(FEW|SCT)(\\d+?)($|\\s)";` FEW will only be found if it has numbers after? I did say: `(\\d+?)`. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped, thanks. :) Added a `\b` boundary to prevent `+SNA` from matching. Let me look at your other regex.

Comment: `(\d+?)` means lazily match digits, until... the `$` or whitespace char. In this context the `?` modifiers the `+` quantifier and makes it lazy rather than greedy (shortest vs longest match). If you want the digits to be optional, just use `\d*`

Comment: Very helpful indeed. Thanks for explaining it to me. Regards!

Answer (score 3):

The `+` character has special meaning, either escape it or place these characters inside of a character class:

```
[-+]
```

If you want to match all substrings, remove the anchors from your regular expression and consider this regex:

```
NSString* expression = @"([-+]?(?:RA|SN|DZ)\\b)"
```

### Edit

If this didn't work, you can use the following to match the `+` character.

```
[-\\x2b]
```

Comment: In xcode (Objective C) (-|\+) gives error "unknown escape sequence". And [+-] does not seem to work either.

Answer (score 1):

Try following regex,

```
.*?(-|\+)?(RA|SN|DZ).*?
```

[image]

Comment: In xcode (Objective C) (-|\+) gives error "unknown escape sequence".

Comment: @IgorTupitsyn  Try with \\+